# Why is my program dropping the most significant figure when reading/writing to a file?

Tags: c++, file-io

I was writing two functions to save a 4-dimensional vector to a file and then reading the vector back into the file.

```
void saveLayer(string filename, int layer){
    ofstream ofile(filename, ios::out | ios::trunc);
    vector<vector<vector<vector<double>>>> oweights(layers[layer]->weights);
    for(vector<vector<vector<double>>> stratg:oweights){
        for(vector<vector<double>>layeri:stratg){
            for(vector<double> neuronq:layeri){
                for(double q:neuronq){
                    ofile<<setprecision(15)<<q;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    vector<vector<vector<double>>> obiases=layers[layer]->biases;
    for(vector<vector<double>>z:obiases){
        for(vector<double> w:z){
            for(double q:w){
                ofile<<setprecision(15)<<q;
            }
        }
    }
    ofile.close();
}

void loadLayer(string filename, int nS, vector<int> layerStruct){
    vector<vector<vector<vector<double>>>> newWeights;
    vector<vector<vector<double>>> newBiases;
    ifstream ifile(filename, ios::in);
    for(int i=0; i<nS; i++){
        vector<vector<vector<double>>> netWeights;
        for(int z=1; z<layerStruct.size(); z++){
            vector<vector<double>> layerWeights;
            for(int x=0; x<layerStruct[z]; x++){
                vector<double> neuronWeights;
                for(int y=0; y<layerStruct[z-1]; y++){
                    double w;
                    ifile>>w;
                    neuronWeights.push_back(w);
                }
                layerWeights.push_back(neuronWeights);
            }
            netWeights.push_back(layerWeights);
        }
        newWeights.push_back(netWeights);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<nS; i++){
        vector<vector<double>> netBiases;
        for(int z=1; z<layerStruct.size(); z++){
            vector<double> layerBiases;
            for(int x=0; x<layerStruct[z]; x++){
                double neuronBias;
                ifile>>neuronBias;
                layerBiases.push_back(neuronBias);
            }
            netBiases.push_back(layerBiases);
        }
        newBiases.push_back(netBiases);
    }
    layers[0]->numStrats=nS;
    layers[0]->weights=newWeights;
    layers[0]->biases=newBiases;
    ifile.close();
}
```

My problem is that when it is supposed to write or read, say, 1.2345, it reads or writes 0.2345, dropping the most significant figure. I don't know if the problem is with the save or load functions. I would greatly appreciate any explanation for why this is.

Comment: Unrelated `for(vector<vector<vector<double>>> stratg:oweights)` is exactly what `auto` was made for. `for(auto stratg:oweights)` is much cleaner, yes? Note though that in both cases deal in values, where references are probably more suitable. Compilers are smart so it may not be making all the copies that have been asked for, but `for(const auto & stratg:oweights)` makes certain of that.

Comment: `write` or `read`? Where does the issue occur? Is the value `0.2345` being written to the file? Then that means the `read` operation is doing just fine. If `1.2345` is being written, but `read` isn't giving the correct value back, then `read` is the problem. Which is it? Have you used a debugger to find out when the problem is happening?

Comment: *I don't know if the problem is with the save or load functions.* You can probably narrow this possibility down by looking at the output file. If the file is incorrect, save is likely the guilty party--assuming some other part of the code doesn't lie to it.

Comment: user4581301 thanks for the tips. I am not sure how to check the output file without using the same reading methods that I am not sure work.

Comment: The files look to be 100% text. Open them up in a text file reader and see what they contain. The problem will likely come down to the lack of spaces between the written values. if you write 1.234 and then 5.678 to the file the file will contain  1.2345.678 which will read back as  1.2345  and 0.678

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no delimiters between the data written to the output file. Given 1.234 and 5.678

```
ofile<<setprecision(15)<<q;
```

will write 1.2345.678 into the output file. All of your numbers are being mushed together into one big blob. When read back

```
ifile>>w;
```

doesn't know where one number was supposed to end and the next was supposed to begin. As a result it reads until if finds a character that cannot possibly be part of a `double`.

eg. 1.2345.678 will be read up to 1.2345 where it finds a second `'.'`. Floating point numbers can't have 2 decimal places (even though this one is a `double`), so the parser stops, leaving .678 in the stream for the next read, and returns 1.2345. Next time around .678 is read and returned as 0.678.

The most significant figure is now mysteriously gone, and because a `double` is only good out to 15 digits you probably won't notice it was stuck to previous number as its 16th digit.

Possible Solution: write a space after each number.

```
ofile<<setprecision(15)<<q << ' ';
```